# Grep with number

Tags: bash, grep, design-patterns

How I can `grep` with number. I have following data

```
[240465] SERVICE ALERT: localhost;demo-jms2:Critical Services;CRITICAL;SOFT;2;Disk Space,OutConnectorResponse-MCASMS,OutConnectorResponse-SPONSORED-SMS,
[240465] SERVICE EVENT HANDLER: localhost;demo-jms2:Critical Services;CRITICAL;SOFT;1;notify-service-by-email
```

I want to `grep` this data with number '2' which is a parameter after 'SOFT'. Here my problem is i am getting both lines when I grep with 2 since 2 contains in the time stamp of second line..

Answer (score 2):

There is already a bunch of answers recommending fixes to your `grep` expression. It can be the right thing to do if you work on a problem interactively, and a quick hack that narrows down the results *right now* is enough for you.

If you're writing a script, I would recommend something like this `awk` command:

```
awk -F';' '{if ($5==2) print}'
```

Or a more readable equivalent provided by @sudo_O in a comment:

```
awk -F';' '$5==2'
```

First we have to reconstruct a *specification* of what you want from your example. You're in the best position to do it reliably, but it *looks* like you want to find `2` in the fifth field of semicolon-separated fields. That's what the above command does.

Comment: Or in more awkish terms `awk -F';' '$5==2'` as the default block is `print`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the pattern `;2;`

```
$ grep ';2;' file
[240465] SERVICE ALERT: localhost;demo-jms2:Critical Services;CRITICAL;SOFT;2;...
```

Or if you only want to match `2` following `SOFT` then use `;SOFT;2;`

```
$ grep ';SOFT;2;' file
[240465] SERVICE ALERT: localhost;demo-jms2:Critical Services;CRITICAL;SOFT;2;...
```

Answer (score 0):

Grep with more context:

```
 grep "SOFT;2;" data
```

Mind the quotes, otherwise the ";" will be interpreted by the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
grep 'SERVICE.*ALERT.*SOFT;2' file
```

I had added more patterns for unicity.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Po "(?<=SOFT;)\d+"
```

with your data

```
kent$  echo "[240465] SERVICE ALERT: localhost;demo-jms2:Critical 
Services;CRITICAL;SOFT;2;Disk Space,OutConnectorResponse-MCASMS,OutConnectorResponse-SPONSORED-SMS,
[240465] SERVICE EVENT HANDLER: localhost;demo-jms2:Critical Services;CRITICAL;SOFT;1;notify-service-by-email"|grep -Po "(?<=SOFT;)\d+"
2
1
```